# What is the object type returning in a join of a hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

When I have the below query it will give me a list of  Product.

```
List<Product>=

getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p ").list();
```

What will it return when there is a join as below.

```
getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p inner join ProductCategory pc where p.id=pc.id").list();
```

Comment: You will receive List<Object[]>.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself and see what it returns? Is it really that difficult?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT p FROM Product p inner join ...` something like that gives you a list of `Product`s.

`FROM Product p inner join ...` something like that gives you a list of arrays.

Comment: Can you please tell what is the reason for that?

Comment: Both are joining tables but the 1st explicitly specifies to return only Product.

Answer (score 5):

It should return `List<Object[]>` as a result. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913057/hibernate-how-to-get-result-from-query-with-multiple-classes) thread

And you should access your entities like

```
for (Object[]> result : query.list()) {
    Product p = (Product) result[0];
    ProductCategory pc = (ProductCategory) result[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a `list` of  objects. You will have to cast them in to `Product`

```
List list = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p inner 
                      join ProductCategory pc where p.id=pc.id").list();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for javax.persistence.Query, you are going to get a List back. Why would you think it should be different?

Answer (score 0):

This class casting from java.lang.object to model class doesn't work in any ways. Below is my code.

```
List<Contactinfo> listStudentInfo = new ArrayList<Contactinfo>();                    
                         //listStudentInfo = dataService.getAllStudent(studentInfo);
                         listStudentInfo = dataService.getStudentInfo();
                         System.out.println(listStudentInfo.size()); 
                         Contactinfo contactinfo = (Contactinfo)listStudentInfo.get(0);
```

But In hibernate, you don't need join if you have both Entity associated with by @Many-to-one or @One-to-one join annotation. Then you need to select one object only , you will automatically get access to other object via the join. Make sure you keep getter(), setter() method for the joining field. Hope this will clarify the situation.