# Hibernate and select with join

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate, and i am having problem with the join. The problem is that, the query return an List of Objects and i don't know how i must manage it

This is the code:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select p.id, p.pokemon, t.types from Pokedex as p JOIN p.assPokTypes t where p.id = '001'");
List lista = query.list();

for(Object row:lista) {
   System.out.println(row);
}
```

This is the table structure:
Pokedex (ID, pokemon) 
AssPokTypes (id_pokemon, id_type, primary_type)

Thanks

Comment: Is different, because he has a only one Class/Table in the query, i have more Class/Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it returns a list of Object array not Objects

```
        List<Object[]> lista = query.list();

      for(Object[] row:lista) {
        System.out.println(row[0]);//Object of the first column
        System.out.println(row[1]);//Object of the second column
       }
```

Comment: No, is a Object. If i try to apply your code, Eclipse give me this error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object"

Comment: My mistake , i edited the answer , array of object is an object thats why it can iterate on it

Comment: Work!! :) therefore, I have a List of Object[ ] that in turn are Object[ ]..right?

Comment: Yes, You will notice that if you are using JPQL even you dont use a typed query here you wont get an "unchecked" warning , the underlying JPA layer knows that the result list will be of type Object[]

Answer (score 0):

Every object from the list is column. 
row[0] - p.id
row[1] - p.pokemon 
....
Iterate list and use columns that you need.

[Hibernate: How to get result from query with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913057/hibernate-how-to-get-result-from-query-with-multiple-classes)