# Eager fetching with multiple selects but without FetchType.EAGER annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch, eager-loading, entitygraph

I want to eagerly fetch one-to-many `List`-s in some use cases (but not always, so `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` won't be good), and I also want JPA to use separate SQL selects to fetch those `List`-s (one select per `List`, not one per `List` item), instead of an SQL join. That's because of the Cartesian products (I have two independent lists).

You may think that I could use a JPA 2.1 entity graph (that's what it's for after all, marking attributes as eager on an ad-hoc manner) or less elegantly `left join fetch` with JPQL (or with criteria API). But these seem to stick to using SQL join (not surprisingly in the case of `left join fetch`), and even if thus they end up with a `MultipleBagFetchException`, they don't fall back to fetching some of the `List`-s in separate SQL selects. Actually my case is a multiple-bags case as well, but before you redirect me to working it around with `Set`-s and such, note that the premise is that I don't want joins (too big Cartesian product). Now, just to tease me, if I annotate the `List` attributes with `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`, Hibernate will be smart enough to fetch the `List`-s in separate selects to avoid the multiple bags (plus I can even force this behavior with Hibernate's `Fetch` annotation). So it seems JPA 2.1 entity graphs fail to deliver the promise of ad-hoc `FetchType.EAGER`, as they behave rather like ad-hoc fetch joins, which we already had before them too. Or do I missing something?

It occurred to me that I should just call `parentEntity.getSomeList().size()` after the initial query that this time wouldn't try to eager fetch the lists, but problem is, I also need to eagerly fetch some attributes of the list items themselves, and I can't specify an entity graph for the above call. I also could create a JPA query myself, which only gets "someList" with said eager fetches (no problem with those), but then how can I put that resulting list back into the `parentEntity`? If I call `parentEntity.setSomeList(fetchedList)`, `parentEntity` becomes dirty (despite that it's not on the owner side of the association), and so it will be SQL update-d (only to spoil the last modification time and optimistic locking version).

Comment: This answer can help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5435405/2387977

Comment: What do you mean? That I could use the native (non-JPA) Hibernate Criteria API  and specify `.setFetchMode("someList", FetchMode.SELECT)` there?

Comment: yes :). I understand that this could be an alternative to you: "_(or with criteria API). But these seem to stick to using SQL join_".

Answer (score 0):

An alternative it's mapping the same table in two different entities. So, when you need the EAGER behaviour with multiple selects, you can use the entity with:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

And when you want the lazy, you use the another entity with:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: Won't it cause problems if I map two entity classes to the same table? Like, if I get them with the same ID, but with different entity classes, the resulting two Java object can't be identical. JPA shouldn't even allow that as far as I know: if the ID-s are the same, the object should be too (within the same persistence context).